# Visual Studio 2006 with C# 4

Tags: c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use C# 4.0 with Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202289/is-it-possible-to-use-c-4-0-with-visual-studio-2008)

Could I use my existing Visual Studio 2006 with latest C# 4?

Thanks.

CK

Comment: Did you mean 2005 or 2008? There is no 2006.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use C# 4 ( .NET 4.0) with 2005 or 2008

Have a look at this answer here as well: [Is it possible to use C# 4.0 with Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202289/is-it-possible-to-use-c-4-0-with-visual-studio-2008/1202298#1202298)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to have Visual Studio 2010 for .NET4.